# X-Frame-Options to SameOrigin Angular Application

Tags: tableau-api, angular11

Trying to load Tableau Report/Dashboard on the Angular app using the IFrames.
As per the documentation setting the JS path as https://<>/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js
then using the tableau Viz object tried to load the report. However it is giving the error
"Refused to display <https://server.tableau.com> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'
How to set the Iframe to avoid this error in Angular 11 application.